# About Gridview Row data bound

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview

Hey guys i am trying to get label value in gridview into string parameter.
On row data bound i have written following code:

```
protected void gvDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        date = ((Label)gvDetail.FindControl("lblDate")).Text;
        if (date == ((Label)gvDetail.FindControl("lblDate")).Text)
        {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

On assigning value in date parameter it gives me error object reference not set to an instance of an object.
The value of the label comes out to be null.
What is wrong in above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use [GridViewRowEventArgs.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.row%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pointless since you are comparing `lblDate.Text` with `lblDate.Text`.

Apart from that, the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Label` is the `GridViewRow` not the `GridView`,

so change:

```
date = ((Label)gvDetail.FindControl("lblDate")).Text;
```

to

```
date = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDate")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code would be following for access label in Row Data Bound Event of grid view

```
protected void gvDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        date = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDate")).Text;
        if (date == ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDate")).Text)
        {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```